# Changing Ring Profile in android from my android application(location based ring profile changing app)

Tags: android, gps, profile

I need to change the ring profile to silent(if in general) when the user reaches, say, his office. Switch it back to normal when he gets back to his home. Basically it is location based ring profile changing app. Any sort of information on this will be helpful. I need working android source code or even tutorials that can help me.